# combining a proc freq statement with proc means statement SAS

Tags: sas

```
proc means data=cervical3 mean qrange median maxdec=2;
    var age R_Risk P_Risk;
    class provider escalation;
    ways 2;
run;

proc freq data=cervical3;
    tables escalation*provider*sex/norow nocol ;
run;
```

I am trying to combine these 2 steps to get a single table summarizing age, R_Risk, P_Risk and sex by escalation and provider (both categorical variables). Im not sure how to accomplish this since sex is a categorical variable and the rest are continuous.

Comment: did you try adding SEX to the CLASS statement to your proc means/proc summary step?

Comment: Why not code SEX as a numeric variable with 1 and 0 the possible values.

Comment: @Tom Looks like OP is using `sex` as a `var` not a `class` variable.

Comment: Sex is coded as 1 and 0.  Adding SEX to CLASS does not give me the info I am looking for, which is the count of males/females by provider type and escalation.  I figured out that adding SEX to VAR will give me % of the dummy code 1, which in my case is male.  This doesnt fully address my issue but at least gives me % males.

Comment: If your question is more "what's the right choice here", you may find a better answer on [stats.se], though you'll want to provide some more information before asking the question there - particularly, give more detail on what analysis you're doing.  Here we don't want or care about that much - we're just telling you how to write programs to do what you want - so you only need to add that if you're going to flag your question for migration.

Comment: For 1/0 variables SUM is count of 1's.  MEAN is percent 1's.  To get count of zeros subtract SUM from \_FREQ_ or N.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you need to decide how you want to analyze `sex`.  Since it's a discrete variable, is it appropriate to do the same calculations as it is with a continuous variable?  Often it is not, but it depends on what you're doing and why.  This is not a programming question, though - it's a data analysis question.

As far as the programming question: there are a few solutions.  If `proc tabulate` will offer all of what you want, you can use that - it can handle some of what `proc means` does alongside `proc freq` basics, as it lets you request different statistics for different crossings.

If it won't handle everything, and you need `proc means` and `proc freq` separately, then your best bet likely is to output the data to datasets from these two procs, and then merge them.  After that, you can `proc print` or `proc report` from those datasets however you prefer.

Here's an example using `proc tabulate`.  Note here the discrete analysis variable I'm using is `age` and the categorical unit is `sex` (mostly because it makes more sense for this particular example) - and note that `age` is placed in the `class` statement, *even though it is a column/analysis variable*.  That is because I do want it broken out by all of its categories.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
class sex age;
var height weight;
tables sex,(age*n (height weight)*(mean qrange median));
run;
```

In your example you'd have your two actual class variables (`escalation` and `provider`) plus `sex` in the class statement, put `escalation provider` before the comma, and `sex` after the comma alongside your three continuous variables.

Comment: I think reversing role of SEX and AGE in your TABULATE tables statement is closer to what was desired.   So the OP's analysis would replace age with provider*escalation as the row dimension in the tables statement.

Comment: @Tom I intentionally swapped the roles of the variables so that OP could see a discrete numeric variable in that spot, but yes I would expect in OP's version that's what would happen (as I explain in the answer).